# Compare Azure's Boosted Decision Tree Regression to Python's GradientBoostingRegressor

Tags: python, azure, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

I am trying to compare Azure's [Boosted Decision Tree Regression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn905801.aspx) to scikit-learn's [GradientBoostingRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html). The purpose for this is that the options in scikit-learn are much better for things like tuning the hyperparmeters.  For example see this [tutorial.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-gradient-boosting-regression-py) I will then build my productionized version in Azure because the API handling is quite nice.

Azure has the following hyperparameter options.
[image]

I think that this should correspond to the settings in GradientBoostingRegressor

```
'max_leaf_nodes': 175,
'min_samples_leaf': 5,
'learning_rate': 0.1, 
'n_estimators': 1500,
```

I also set

```
'loss': 'ls'
```

because I am pretty sure Azure uses least squares. Anyway, I get a slightly different output. I use Root Mean Squared Error as my evaluation metric.

```
Azure Test RMSE: 2222
scikit-learn Test RMSE: 2446
```

Which may not be much of an issue but there is a larger difference in my training error.

```
Azure Train RMSE: 1684
scikit-learn Train RMSE: 2422
```

I do not know what function Azure uses to measure the quality of a split. In scikit-learn I have tried both the standard mean squared error and the one with the improvement by Friedman. I get similar answers.

The other unknown is the handling of categorical feature in Azure. In scikit-learn I have used [factorize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) to achieve Ordinal Encoding as well as [get_dummies()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) for one hot encoding . Both methods give results much closer to each other than to Azure. There is the possibility that Azure handles categoricals natively in one column with an "=" for the decision instead of the ">" used for numerical values. My understanding of the algorithm is that if both Ordinal and One-Hot encoding give similar answers then this would also yield similar results.

I would appreciate any insight into what could be the possible differences between these algorithms. I know [XGBOOST](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has some [differences](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202858/loss-function-approximation-with-taylor-expansion) related to the loss function and splitting method.

Comment: Maybe you can post a feedback at [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to report your consideration.

Comment: Done https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/30976669-give-more-algorithm-details-for-boosted-decision-t